# Editing/styling text from file/array and putting it back in order, styled?

Tags: php, joomla, file-get-contents, styling

**tl;dr**
I'm trying to style specific lines from a textfile, and in the end being able to show it on the page in the original order.

**info:** My page is running Joomla with the sourcerer extension.
Sample content of the wishlist:

```
wish 2
wish 3

§Category 1
    C1_wish1
    C1_wish2
    C1_wish3

§Category 2

    C2_wish1
    C2_wish2
    C2_wish3

wish 4 - link https://google.com
wish 5
wish 6
```

**Full story**
I'm trying to set up a simple site for my family that can display our wishlists.
We're currently keeping the files on dropbox and so far I've figured out how to make the site read the file.

I would like for the script to  make every line that starts with a special character, bold, and all other lines to be put in a bullet-list, but not the bolded ones.

**bonus round:** If there's any links in the text it would be insane if they could be clickable.

**The Problem**
Right now I do a preg_match to check if any lines contains a specific Character, and if it does it's put in an array, if not, it'll be put in another.
I don't know how to run the check on the lines, apply the styling only to some of them and then return them in the correct order so I can display them correctly on the page.

**My code**

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/html");

$string = file_get_contents('https://dropboxlink/wishlist.txt');
$array = explode("\n",$string);

foreach($array as $arr) 
{
 if(!(preg_match('#^-#', $arr))) 
   {
   $output[] = $arr;
   }

 else
   {
   $output2[] = $arr;
   }
}
$out = implode("\n",$output);
$out2 = implode("\n",$output2);

echo $out;
echo $out2;
?>
```

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development, please join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and post all Joomla questions there.  To create a [mcve] -- show your sample input, your coding attempt, and your exact desired output.

Comment: You should not use regex to parse valid html.  Please [edit] your question to provide a realistic sample html document and your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are moving the lines into separate arrays! Just iterate through line by line and work out what should be where!

**Using `preg_match`**

```
$array = explode("\n", $text); // Split text into lines
$open_list = false;            // Set sub list flag to false
echo "<ul>";                   // Begin list

// Loop through each line of text
foreach($array as $line){

    // If the line is blank, skip it
    if(preg_match("/^\s*$/", $line)){
        echo "<br>";
        continue;
    }

    // Check if the line is a category heading
    if(preg_match("/^§/", $line)){

        // Check to see if we're already on a sub list
        // if we are then close it and set flag to false
        if($open_list){
            echo "</ul>";
            $open_list = false;
        }

        $line = trim($line, "§");  // Trim the special character from the line
        echo "<li><b>{$line}</b></li><ul>";     // Print out the line and begin a sub list
        $open_list = true;                      // Set flag to true
        continue;                               // Skip rest of code block, we don't need it for a category
    }

    // We only get here IF the line isn't a category and isn't blank!

    // Check to see if the line starts with a non-white space character
    // and whether or not the sub list flag is set. If both conditions
    // are true then close the sub list and set flag to false
    if(preg_match("/^[\S]/", $line) && $open_list){
        echo "</ul>";
        $open_list = false;
    }

    // Turn URLs into hyperlinks and print out the line
    $line = preg_replace("/([\w:\/\.?=%]+\.[\w:\/\.?=%]+)/", "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>", $line);
    echo "<li>{$line}</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";  // Close list
```

**Alternative**

We don't *have* to use the `ul | ol` HTML lists we can add list properties in css to other elements:

```
// Define styles for each element
$category  = "font-weight: bold;";
$sub_list  = "padding-left: 20px; display: list-item; list-style-type: circle; list-style-position: inside;";
$main_list = "padding-left: 10px; display: list-item; list-style-type: disc; list-style-position: inside;";

$text = "
wish 2
wish 3

§Category 1
    C1_wish1
    C1_wish2
    C1_wish3

§Category 2

    C2_wish1
    C2_wish2
    C2_wish3

wish 4 - link https://google.com
wish 5
wish 6
";

$array = explode("\n", $text); // Split text into lines

// Loop through each line of text
foreach($array as $line){

    // Check if the line is blank
    if(preg_match("/^\s*$/", $line)){
        echo "<br>";
    }

    // Check if the line is a category
    elseif(preg_match("/^§/", $line)){
        $line = trim($line, "§");
        echo "<div style=\"{$category}\">{$line}</div>";
    }

    // Check if the line is a sub list
    elseif(preg_match("/^\s+\S+/", $line)){
        $line = trim($line, "\s");
        $line = preg_replace("/([\w:\/\.?=%]+\.[\w:\/\.?=%]+)/", "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>", $line);  // Replace URLs with hyperlinks
        echo "<div style=\"{$sub_list}\">{$line}</div>";
    }

    // Otherwise it's a normal list item
    else{
        $line = preg_replace("/([\w:\/\.?=%]+\.[\w:\/\.?=%]+)/", "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>", $line);   // Replace URLs with hyperlinks
        echo "<div style=\"{$main_list}\">{$line}</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: `I'm not sure why you are moving the lines into separate arrays! Just iterate through line by line and work out what should be where!`

Because I'm not experienced in PHP or coding, I didnt know how to edit them as the code ran through the array.

 So I have the wishlists info from the dropbox file. Is there a way to use those and keep the line breaks but still let it do the formatting? The .txtfile is encoded as UTF-8 already.

Tried doing this   
`$rawtext = file_get_contents("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/t0duth39y8gammo/wishlist.txt");

$text = utf8_decode($rawtext);  
`

Comment: @Songfire If you still want the line breaks then you just need to change the first `if` statement (the one which says `// If the line is blank, skip it`) by adding `echo "<br>";` before the `continue;`. Let me know if that's working for you!

Comment: That does work perfectly! Thank you Steven. 
If the header is defining the charset as utf8 and the txtfile is already utf8 encoded, do I then need the encode/decode? part ion the if statement, I could also change the symbol to something else if it makes the code a bit simpler.

Comment: The reason for the `decode` is because your "special" character is a 2 byte character and the code uses the first byte (`$line[0]`)... So yes you could change the symbol to, for example, `#` and you wouldn't need it. Alternatively we could change the if statement to `if(preg_match('/^§/', $line))` instead

Comment: `preg_match` is probably the easiest solution (I've added the code above). Not sure why I didn't do that in the first place tbh!

Comment: Aww that's wild! I was wary of using pound symbols because I was afraid I wouldn't be able to make it distringuish between a link with a # inside and a Headline :) 

thank you so much for your help, it is greatly appreciated :)!

Comment: i discovered a thing in your code, it's a minor problem but I can't figure out if it's the right way to do it. Right now, my headings all get thrown in a sublist, can I just remove the <li> tags,  or will that destroy the rest of the code setup?

Comment: It won't destroy the code... However, simply removing the `li` will still leave the heading indented it will only remove the `bullet point` marker? If you don't want it indented then you need to close out the `ul` which would mean adjusting the code slightly

Comment: @Songfire I've added an alternative solution which gives you less complicated and easier to understand and manipulate code!

Comment: Sorry for keep commenting, I know the guidelines are against this, but i'm not high enough level on this site to open a chat window, probably a good idea :)

Thanks for the second solution. I had problems with indentation if they came after a sublist item that was not indeted already. I tried to do kind awhat you did:
Setup  if else statements to check for three levels of indentation but couldnt figure out how to check for tabbed indentations and not only "any" whitespace. I guess `"/^\s+\S+/`
is doing that? is it called regex?, any help on how to understand the information in it?

Comment: @Songfire Unfortunately your reputation isn't high enough to participate in chat! (20+ required) `/^\s+\S+/` checks for one or more white space characters `\s`(e.g. tab or space) followed  by one or more non-white space characters `\S` (i.e. text). The `+` is a quantifier that specifies `1 or more`. If you only want tabs instead of spaces then use `\t` instead of `\s`. If you only want one specified then get rid of the `+` after it.

Comment: Cheers. Thank you for helping me this much, I'm really happy and so is the wife hehe :)

Comment: @Songfire No problem! If this answered your question you can mark it as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) and help build your reputation on StackOverflow! Good luck with the project

Comment: It most certainly did :) Thank you again!